# Migrate local mongodump into a docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, migrate, mongodump

I was using the local mongo database. Now I dockerized my entire application on another remote system including MongoDB. So that, I need to migrate my local mongo dump into the docker container.


How can I import all the data from local MongoDB to the docker container's MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should work:

- Dump the data from local mongodb
- Copy dump file to remote system
- Copy dump file to mongo container using `docker cp` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):
- Enter mongo container: `docker exec -it [container_id] bash`
- Restore the dump using inside the container.